# How to compile boost with clang on windows?

Tags: windows, boost, mingw, clang

I'm trying to configure Sublime Text 2 to use clang (with SublimeClang plugin).
Everything seems to be fine, except the fact that clang have problems with parsing boost files.

To be specific I get this error: "Error - variadic function cannot use fastcall calling convention". I already found topic about it (http://llvm.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=12535) and it seems to be boost bug. Regardless I would be happy to somehow disable this error. I was trying to use ms compatibility mode(-fms-compatibility) but it doesn't seem to change anything.

Is there any way to disable this error or for now there is no way to compile boost with clang on windows?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For now I "solved" this problem by editing is_member_function_pointer.hpp file anch changing calling convention
Since I need it only for my IDE I doesn't really care if it would link or work properly.
However looks like it's bug on the boost side and it need to be fixed there.

Comment: If no one will come with better solution soon I'll accept this answer.